# How can I transform a int to a byte?

Tags: c, arduino

I'm creating a temperature (Celsius) node for my Arduino. I'm sending byte data from my node to the master-node (also running Arduino) by cheap RF links so I need to convert a temperature (float) to a byte that Im sending over the air.

I know that with a simple byte I'm limited by 255 values of a byte, but if I set the precision to 0.5 that will be more then good enough for there weather we are having. So I've set the range to [-30, 97]

When that is set 0 degrees Celsius = byte value 60.

```
float ConvertFromByte(byte b)
{
  // todo
}

byte ConvertFromFloat(float f)
{
  // todo
}
```

In the ConvertFromFloat I'll need to round to the nearest 0.5, and then apply the method of conversion. ConvertFromByte only has to to the last bit, but in reverse.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sounds like you need a basic transmission protocol. Size, data, checksum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I'll bite if only because of always being asked how to round to specific values and how to type cast.

Assuming you start at byte value 0 being equal to temperature value -30, and you have byte value 255 equal to temperature value 97 degrees and you want every byte value to increment the temperature value by 0.5 degrees Celsius, your maximum would actually be at CurrentTemp = LowestTemp + (ByteVal*IncrementTemp) = -30 + (255*0.5) = 97.5 degrees and this will be your equation. Therefore:

```
const int LowestTemp       -30
const float MaxTemp        97.5
const float IncrementTemp  0.5
bool retry_flag;


float ConvertFromByte(byte b)
{
  /*returns CurrentTemp*/

  return ((float)(LowestTemp + (b*IncrementTemp)));
}

byte ConvertFromFloat(float f)
{
  /*returns ByteVal*/
  float CurrentTemp = (int)(f/IncrementTemp);
  CurrentTemp *= IncrementTemp;
  if((CurrentTemp<LowestTemp)||(CurrentTemp>MaxTemp)) retry_flag = 1;
  return ((byte)((CurrentTemp - LowestTemp)/IncrementTemp));
}
```

The method of rounding can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_a_specified_increment) and makes use of the method of first dividing the number by the increment, rounding to a whole number and then multiplying by the increment again.

The method of typecasting is merely telling value x to be of a type *cast* by writing *(cast) x* as above. Here I use the fact that *int* does not contain fractions to quickly round CurrentTemp to the nearest whole number.

Note also that your code will need to check if the retry flag is set before using the value to pass via RF. There will be no errors, however the value passed will be completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have already figured out the desired range of temperatures, so all you need to do is scaling the values 0..255 to and from that range.

To get from float [-30..97] to integral [0..255] in half-degree steps you need to add 30 to the number, multiply it by two, truncate the fraction, apply limits on both sides (negative numbers become zero; numbers above 255 become 255)

```
float temp;
float x = temp+30;
if (x < 0) return 0; // Apply lower limit
x *= 2;
return x > 255 ? 255 : (byte)x; // Apply upper limit and truncate
```

To get from integral [0..255] to float [-30..97], convert the value to `float`, divide by 2, and subtract 30:

```
float res = ((float)x)/2 - 30;
```